# Why is reactive variable changing when it is not assigned to v-model

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm fairly new to the composition API but it's been somewhat straight forward so far.

I'm making an Axios call that is returning some data;

```
const transaction = ref({});
let pbl = reactive({});

const getPayByLinkTransaction = () => {
    axios({
        method: "get",
        url: "pay-by-link",
        params: {
            merchantUuid: import.meta.env.VITE_MERCHANT_UUID,
            uuid: route.params.uuid,
        },
    })
        .then((res) => {
            transaction.value = res.data;
            pbl = res.data;            
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            console.log(e);
        });
}

getPayByLinkTransaction();
```

Then I have the following textfield:

```
<v-text-field v-model="transaction.reference" variant="solo" class="mb-1"
:rules="config?.fields?.reference?.required ? required : []"></v-text-field>

PBL - {{ pbl.reference }} <br>
Transaction - {{ transaction.reference }}
```

The **reference** key contains John Doe to start off with.

What's strange is that when I start typing into the textfield, it's changing **reference** in both the **transaction** and **pbl** object.

As the v-model is attached to **transaction.reference**, should it not only change the variable in the **transaction** object?

Why is the **pbl** object changing too?

What I'm after are two objects where one contains the original data and the other contains modified data if the user were to amend any details.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to reproduce the problem using `Composition API` in both Vue 2 and Vue 2.

So, here is my assumption about what's going on.

You are assigning the same object from `res.data` to `transaction` and to `pbl`.
Since it is the same object, the change of `reference` over `transaction.reference` changes also `pbl.reference`

### Here is the simple Vue 2 playground using `Options API` to understand the problem.

```js
const App = { 
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      myObj: { id: 1, counter: 0 },
      myObjCopy: {}
    }
  },
  methods: {
     replaceObj() {
      let obj = { id: this.myObj.id + 1, counter: 0 };
      this.myObj = obj;
      this.myObjCopy = obj;
    },
    plus() {
      this.myObj.counter++; 
    }
  }
}
const app = new Vue(App);
```

```css
#app { line-height: 2; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app">
<button type="button" @click="replaceObj()">Replace My Object</button><hr/>
My Object Id: {{myObj.id}}<br/>
Counter: {{myObj.counter}}
<button type="button" @click="plus()">+1</button><br/>
<hr/>
My Object Copy Id: {{myObjCopy.id}}<br/>
Counter: {{myObjCopy.counter}}
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.7.14/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
```

### The interesting this is, the reactivity in Vue 3 behaves different.

```
// true in 2.7, false in 3.x
reactive(foo) === foo;
```

The Vue 3 `reactive()` function create a Proxy object. Check the [Behavior Differences from Vue 3](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration-vue-2-7.html#Behavior-Differences-from-Vue-3)

```js
const { createApp, ref, reactive } = Vue;
const App = { 
  setup() {    
    let obj = { id: 1, counter: 0 };
    const myObj = ref(obj);
    let myObjCopy = reactive(obj);    
    const plus = () => {
      myObj.value.counter++; 
    }    
    const replaceObj = () => {
      let obj = { id: myObj.value.id + 1, counter: 0 };
      myObj.value = obj;
      myObjCopy = obj;
    }
    return { myObj, myObjCopy, plus, replaceObj}
  }
}
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<div id="app">
<button type="button" @click="replaceObj()">Replace My Object</button><br/><br/>
My Object Id: {{myObj.id}}<br/>
Counter: {{myObj.counter}}
<button type="button" @click="plus()">+1</button><br/>
<hr/>
My Object Copy Id: {{myObjCopy.id}}<br/>
Counter: {{myObjCopy.counter}}
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but I'm failing to see what the problem is here. I've done this in Vue2 using the options API without a problem. I fetch the data once, assign it to 2 different variables so that I have an original version. The textfield v-model is connected to transaction.reference so surely only the transaction object should change? Isn't what I'm doing essentially is creating 2 different variables that contain the same data but aren't linked in any way?

Comment: What version of Vue do you use now with `Composition API`, Vue 2 or Vue 3?

Comment: "Isn't what I'm doing essentially is creating 2 different variables that contain the same data but aren't linked in any way" - No. Please read Docs about Objects in JavaScript.

Comment: Hi Tolbxela, I don't understand why the Reactivity in Vue 3 behaves in this manner. Nikola's suggestion of using the spread operator works but I don't actually understand the logic here.

I'm making an API call and storing the response in 2 different variables. Are you saying that the ```transaction```  and ```pbl``` objects are both just pointers to ```res.data```?

If this is the case, is using the spread operator the solution for this problem moving forward?

Comment: Exactly: transaction and `pbl` objects are both just pointers to `res.data` Object, since Objects in JavaScript are passed by Reference (a pointer to the Object)

Answer (score 2):

Try to copy object by value, not reference:

```js
const {ref, reactive} = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const data1 = ref({})
    let data2 = reactive({})
    const byReference = {ref: 'reference'}
    data1.value = byReference
    data2 = byReference
    
    const byValue = {ref: 'value'}
    const data3 = ref({})
    let data4 = reactive({})
    data3.value = byValue
    data4 = {...byValue}
    
    return {
      data1, data2, data3, data4
    };
  },
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <input v-model="data1.ref" />
  {{data1.ref}}
  {{data2.ref}}
  <input v-model="data3.ref" />
  {{data3.ref}}
  {{data4.ref}}
</div>
```

Comment: So it seems by using the spread operator, it solves the problem but I'm still not understanding why this problem exists. I'm making an API call and storing the response in 2 different variables. Surely when I'm storing the API response it is done via value and not reference?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is the understanding of how the Objects are threated in JavaScript.

```
const obj1 = { data : { value: 1 } }
const obj2 = obj1.data;
console.log( obj1.data === obj2 ); // --> true
```

Here is another very simple playground to demonstrate it.

```js
const obj1 = { data : { value: 1 } }
console.log(`obj1.data.value = ${obj1.data.value}`);
// --> obj1.data.value = 1

const obj2 = obj1.data;
obj2.value++;
console.log(`obj1.data.value = ${obj1.data.value}`);
// --> obj1.data.value = 2

console.log(`obj1.data == obj2 : ${obj1.data == obj2}`);
// --> true 

// even the JavaScript object destructuring assignment 
// doesn't break the connection to original data Object
const { data } = obj1;
data.value++;
console.log(`obj1.data.value = ${obj1.data.value}`);
// --> obj1.data.value = 3

// this works, since 'value' is passed by value, not reference
const obj3 = { value: obj1.data.value }
obj3.value++;
console.log(`obj3.value = ${obj3.value}`);
// --> obj3.value = 4
console.log(`obj1.data.value = ${obj1.data.value}`);
// --> obj1.data.value = 3

// the other way is using the Spread Syntax
const obj4 = {...obj1.data}
obj4.value++;
console.log(`obj4.value = ${obj4.value}`);
// --> obj4.value = 4
console.log(`obj1.data.value = ${obj1.data.value}`);
// --> obj1.data.value = 3
```

Comment: Also check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3638034/2487565

Comment: Thank you for that Tolbxela. This is something I've never encountered before surprisingly.

Comment: Can you please accept one of the answers? Thanks!